# Return counted users based on a status

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have the following PostgreSQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    login_name character varying(255),
    status character varying(10), // it can be enabled/disabled
    created_at timestamp(6)
)
```

I want to create SQL query to get summary statistics. For example for August how many enabled and disabled users I have in total:

I tried:

```
SELECT ID, 
  DATE(CREATED_AT) AS date, 
  COUNT(*) AS enabled, 
  COUNT(*) AS disabled 
FROM users 
WHERE (created_at BETWEEN '2022-05-02 06:58:24.620396' AND '2023-05-02 06:58:24.620396') 
GROUP BY DATE(created_at), id
```

But I get this result:

[image]

I want to get the data like this:

[image]

Do you know how I can implement this query properly?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: Why are you expecting to receive dates such as 6/2/2023 and 7/2/2023 when your `WHERE` clause clearly prevents those dates from being included in the query?

Comment: @GMB here it is: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2w2mbVbQMqhLKtnHtWi8o9/0

Comment: Also, why don't you have the ID column in your sample output above? You have it in the SELECT statement, but not in the output.

Comment: Thanks @PeterPenzov, but: (1) that's not tabular text (which should be included in the question) (2) the fiddle itself raises several errors

Comment: @Isolated yes, I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** you are looking to group your users by the month they were created, and count how many are currently enabled/disabled, then you can just use conditional aggregation:

```
select date_trunc('month', created_at) created_month,
    count(*) filter (where status = 'enabled' ) cnt_enabled,
    count(*) filter (where status = 'disabled') cnt_disabled
from mytable
group by date_trunc('month', created_at)
```

Comment: I get `ERROR:  column "month" does not exist
LINE 1: select date_trunc(month, created_at) created_month,` Maybe becasue I use PostgreSQL version 15?

Comment: Thanks, One additional question: I expect to have around one million of rows into table users. Is there some more optimized SQL that can be used?

Comment: By the way did you missed `WHERE (created_at BETWEEN .....' AND '.....')`? I need to specify date range from params.

Comment: @PeterPenzov: you can just add back your `where` clause to the query. As for performance, this should be as efficient as it gets. Consider posting a new question with more information about your data structure and the explain plan of the query if that's not running fast enough.

Comment: I have one more question: maybe is better to add `as` like this `date_trunc('month', created_at) as created_month`?

Comment: @PeterPenzov: `as` is optional here, so it’s up to you to use it or not